# AngularJS dynamic injection of modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

Is there a way to perform dependency injections dynamically? Like injecting modules later and not when creating the root app?

So the situation is that I have a website. And I would like to make the website as one all-containing ng-app instead having just the content of the page as the ng-app. (Imagine the site having a navigation menu and then a body for content; right now, I have the content body as an ng-app, and then bootstrapped the navigation menu as another app since the menu is actually kind of complex.) But now I want to make it so that the entire site is one big ng-app and that it will contain both the body content and the navigation menu (and maybe other applications in here.)

The problem is that since this is a website, there are going to be many pages within the site, and each page would require a different set of modules. The navigation menu module would be common and would be part of the base module, but how can I inject/load a different set of modules depending on what page it is?

Comment: you are describing the functions that `ng-route`, or the 3rd party replacement, `ui-router`, provide. unfortunately, your question is too broad to really answer how these modules would apply in your particular usage scenario.

Comment: share your code first

Answer (score 0):

You can use the powerful [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and a lazy loader like [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad) to dynamically load modules on different routes. This will also help you to reduce the size of initial JavaScript load. Here is an example for using it with Webpack: https://github.com/ay13/webpack-angular-oclazyload